# When using sjPlot::tab_model() how can I convert the estimates and CI to scientific notation?

Tags: r

I am working with a variable containing very large numbers (up to eight hundred fifty-two quadrillion!) and I have made some simple mixed-effects models. I am using sjPlot::tab_model() to create the publication version but I cannot get it to convert the estimates and confidence interval into scientific notation. I found the argument to format the p value, but not the estimates themselves.

Some example code:

```
ID <- round(runif(30, min = 1, max = 10))
Conc <- runif(30, min = 8.050e+12, max = 8.520e+18)
Year <- round(runif(30, min = 2000, max = 2005))

dat <- bind_cols("ID" = ID, 
          "Conc" = Conc, 
          "Year" = Year)
dat

# Mixed-effects model
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)

testmod <- lmer(Conc ~ Year + (1|ID), data = dat)
tab_model(testmod)
```

I have tried the including scientific = TRUE, tried formatting the models before calling tab_model and looked through the reference guide but can't work out how to do it. I should add that I have three models I am placing together in tab_model(), so ideally a solution that will work when calling multiple models at once.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this with `sjPlot`, but using the `modelsummary` package version 1.4.0.9000, you can use the `fmt_sci()` function. This version is only available from Github currently:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart R completely for the change to take effect. Then,

```r
packageVersion("modelsummary")
# [1] '1.4.0.9000'

library(lme4)
library(modelsummary)
set.seed(1024)
ID <- round(runif(30, min = 1, max = 10))
Conc <- runif(30, min = 8.050e+12, max = 8.520e+18)
Year <- round(runif(30, min = 2000, max = 2005))
dat <- data.frame("ID" = ID, "Conc" = Conc, "Year" = Year)
testmod <- lmer(Conc ~ Year + (1|ID), data = dat)

modelsummary(testmod, fmt = fmt_sci(digits = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Vincent - this is very helpful and interesting to learn a new package. I appreciate you taking the time to help.